# Dropbox unique file ID

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, webhooks

I store the files of dropbox into my app using the `((FileMetadata) entry).getId();`

The main problem is when I receive a webhook with a DeleteMetadata it doesn't have the method `getId`, so I don't know what file is deleted. I have to store the path instead of the id?

By the other hand, when I use `client.files().download(path)` this method requires a path. Can I use the unique Id obtained using `((FileMetadata) entry).getId()` to download a file?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/webhooks#documentation: _“Note that only the user IDs and accounts with file changes are provided. Your app is expected to call `/files/list_folder/continue` to find out what files changed using the latest cursor your app previously stored for that account.”_

Comment: I know that. The problem is when I use `result.getEntries()` on the case of DeletedMetada there isn't the method getId(), so I don't know what files is deleted because I store them on my app using that unique ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dropbox API doesn't return the file ID for `DeletedMetadata`, but I'll pass this along as a feature request.

That being the case, if you need to the ID for the deleted file, you'll need to record and retrieve it based on the file you last saw at that path, before the deletion.

And yes, [the `download` method](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/DbxUserFilesRequests.html#download-java.lang.String-) does support file IDs in the `path` parameter.